# Require module in Atom's init.coffee

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I've already Google'd for an answer, since this is a common problem, but all the replies point in using alternatives instead of explaining why this doesn't work, so I'm asking here.

I put this code in my Atom's init.coffee script:
    beautify = require('js-beautify').html

But Atom fails with `Failed to load init.coffee` and `Cannot find module 'js-beautify'`. Curiously enough, this works on a package and this works if I type the exact same code on Atom's console.

Of course, I could write a package for this, in fact there are a couple available, this is just an example because I want to learn how to require modules from init.coffee for future tweaks.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require()` from `init.coffee`, Atom looks for those modules in its own path. An example of where you might want to do that is if you had `oni = require('oniguruma')` to get access to regular expression functions.

In order to get to `js-beautify`, you have to specify its complete path. So far, only explicitly declaring the entire absolute path has worked for me:

```
beaut = require 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\.atom\\packages\\atom-beautify\\node_modules\\js-beautify'

console.log beaut
```

In practice, the most reliable way to use a module like this is to globally install it so that you can link to your global NPM folder. Linking to a module inside a package will break if the package is ever uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Holland :) This was more or less what I expected, but the problem I see here is that in Atom's console I can actually do `require('js-beautify')` and it works, so even if the module is not included in Atom, it is in my machine from other packages using it, am I right? Then, why it doesn't work from `init.coffee`? And that leads to my second question: let's assume `js-beautify` is NOT on my machine. OK, then why `require('js-beautify')` works from `atom-beautify` (an Atom's package)? Is it downloaded by Atom when it is required by a package?

Comment: I don't know why you can get to it like that from the console but not `init.coffee`. I have, however, figured out how to make it work, so I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Again, thanks for the example, Holland. I think I know why `require` was working from the console: I had `atom-beautify` installed and even if I removed the package the `js-beautify` module was still present in some kind of compilation-cache from `node.js` or Electron, I don't know. The thing is that the module was there. Why it works from the console and not from `init.coffee` unless a full path was provided is beyond me, but anyway your answer works for me! Thanks A LOT!